# DataSet Editor is missing from the “Open With” dialog in VS2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to get this option back? it's defaulting to an xml editor. It would be nice to have dataset designer back so that I can edit the typed dataset.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try to run “devenv /resetsettings” or
>   “devenv /setup” in Visual Studio 2005
>   Command Prompt. I hope it can resolve
>   this issue.

[SOURCE](http://forums.asp.net/p/1116852/2813817.aspx)